# Data transfer rate with Gigabit NIC and Switch over Cat-6 cable

Tags: networking, data-transfer, gigabit-ethernet, cat6

I have 2 machines connected over Gigabit NIC with CAT-6 cable through a Gigabit switch. One machine is running Windows 10 and the other running Hyper-V Standalone Server 2016. While I was transferring files from my Windows machine to the Hyper-V Server I noticed the transfer rate always staying below 12MB/s. So, looked like one of the machines is operating at 100mbps link, not 1Gbps.

On the Windows 10 machine, I checked the speed of the network adapter and it says 1.0 Gbps -

[image]

Still I manually set the "Speed & Duplex" setting of the adapter to 1.0 Gbps Full Duplex -

[image]

No improvement. Still below 12MB/s.

I cannot do the same on the Hyper-V server since it doesn't have any UI, and I don't know how to do them from command line.

So what could be the possible issue? And is it possible to check adapter speed status, or change the "Speed & Duplex" setting from the command line?

NB: I'm not transferring files to a VM.

Comment: What link rate is reported by `Get-NetAdapter` on the Hyper-V physical server? (And are you sure manually setting the link rate on one end isn't _causing_ problems?)

Comment: @grawity, I set the link rate manually after I noticed the transfer rate, not before. Didn't check anything on Hyper-V server, but will do. thanks for the command. Using the Hyper-V server out of curiosity in my home-lab; I'm not a server-guy :(

Comment: It's not sure that your modification had any effect. You could find the adapter speed on the server using a command-line such as `wmic NIC where "NetEnabled='true'" get "Name","Speed"`.

Comment: @harrymc, thanks a lot. Ran the command and it says `Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter     100000000`. So, that's a 100mbps link, right?

Comment: Yes, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the adapter speed on the server using the command-line:

```
wmic NIC where "NetEnabled='true'" get "Name","Speed"
```

A speed of 100 mbps will be reported as `100000000`.
A speed of 1 Gbps will be reported as   `1000000000`.